# Comparing std::string with constants vs comparing char arrays with constants In C++

Tags: c++, stdstring, arrays

I am trying to make a little text adventure to get a handle on C++.

```
cin >> keyboard1;  
if ((keyboard1 == "inv")inventory(inv);
```

This will work if keyboard1 is a string, but won't if it's a char array, is this because I haven't included the null at the end of the constant?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I indented four spaces, that has worked before...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let'say your code is the following:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::string s;
    std::cin >> s;
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
    if (s == "inv") {
        std::cout << "Got it" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This works as expected because of the way the stl class `string` overrides the `==` operator.

You cannot expect the following code to work instead:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *s = (char *)calloc(10, sizeof(char));
    std::cin >> s;
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
    if (s == "inv") {
         std::cout << "Got it" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

because you are comparing s, which is the address where the string starts to a constant string (which, by the way, is automatically null-terminated by the compiler).

You should use strcmp to compare "c-strings":

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *s = (char *)calloc(10, sizeof(char));
    std::cin >> s;
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
    if (strcmp(s, "inv") == 0) {
        std::cout << "Got it" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This works.

Answer (score 2):

No, the reason it won't work is because you will be comparing the address of the memory that represents each string. Use `strcmp` / `wcscmp` instead.

The reason why comparing a string and a constant work is because the string class will have an equality operator defined (e.g. `bool StringClass:operator==(const char* pszString)`).

Comment: Oh i get it. So i could compare a char array if i totally reinvented the wheel. Thanks that helped a lot

Comment: @Hagbard: No, you can't, because that would involve overloading an operator for just primitive types, which is not allowed.

Comment: @DeadMG I meant to suggest that I could create a class based on the char array and overload the == operator on that class, but since that and a bunch of other nice features are already packaged in the string class it would be reinventing an inferior wheel.

Comment: Indeed. And if you just used the char type then your code wouldn't support unicode either.

Answer (score 0):

If `keyboard1` is a char array, then `if (keyboard1 == "inv")` is performing a simple pointer comparison (both become `char*`).

When `keyboard1` is a string, it can call an `operator==(cosnt string&, const char*)` if one exists, otherwise, if the string has the non-explicit constructor `string(const char *s)`, the constant `"inv"` would be implicitly converted to a string object, and `operator==(const string&,const string&)` applied.